How do I find the total amount of possible card combinations in a larger deck?
I am trying to figure out how to count cards in a larger deck (143 cards and 11 suits). I thought this would be an easy solve but its proving far more tricky than I had anticipated.

Collect all cards with "5" on it (so 11). I draw with replacement 7 of of them, what's the probability I will observe: On set of 3 matching suits, 2 sets of matching suits that are all unique (AAA BB CC).

What I tried was this: Since there are 11 suits, I choose 1 for the three-match (11C1), and I repeat this for the 2 sets of the two-matches: (10C1) and (9C1).
$\dbinom{11}1 * \dbinom{10}1 * \dbinom{9}1 = 990$
Next, I arranged the actual cards, rather simple like this: $\dbinom{7!}{3!2!2!} = 210$
Next, I found the total probability: $11^7 = 19,487,171$
So, all together:   $\frac{990 * 210}{19,487,171} = 0.01067$
Which is wrong.

I draw 4 cars without replacement out of 143 cards, how many different ways, regardless of order, can I get exactly three "Aces" and exactly one "Heart"?

For this, I chose the aces, then multiplied it by the heart: $\dbinom{11}3 * \dbinom{13}1 = 2145.$
Which is also wrong. I thought these counting strategies would work, but I don't really know what other approach I'm not seeing here? If anyone could give me a hint, I would seriously appreciate it.

The sets with two elements are the same length, so it should be $\binom{11}1\cdot\binom{10}{2}.$

So you've counted twice the case when the suits are $A,B,C$ by selecting $A,B,C$ in order, or selecting $A,C,B$ in order.

Can you elaborate a little on the second point, I'm not sure I catch what you mean?

If you pick the suits $A,B,C$ and the order $1121332$ you get $AABACCB.$ If you chose $A,C,B$ and the order $1231223$ you also get $AABACCB.$ You've counted it twice.

so all I have to do is change it from (11 choose 1) * (10 choose 1) * (9 choose 1) to (11 choose 1) * (10 choose 2)?

For the 2nd question, you need to split into 2 distinct cases : draw Ace of hearts+2 other aces+ one card, not heart and not ace. And then, draw 3 aces (excluding ace of heart)+ one heart(excluding ace of heart).  And at the end, you need to add the result of these 2 computations.

For the first part, since errors are often made, it might help you to "mechanise" the process, so to say, as
$\textbf{[Lay Down Pattern] x [Permute pattern]}$, thus
$32200000000 : \left[\dfrac{7!}{3!2!2!}\right]\left[\dfrac{11!}{1!2!8!}\right] = 103950$
and $Pr = \dfrac{103950}{11^7}, \approx 5.334\%$
For the second part,
($3$ non-heart aces + $1$ non-ace heart) + ($3$ aces incl. ace of hearts, and $1$ non-heart non-ace )
$$\binom{10}3\binom{12}1 + \binom{10}2\binom11\cdot10\cdot12 =6840$$

Are you having any doubts ? Ifso, feel free to ask.
